# Parsing Fluidity data from dumpsys eve

Tags: regex

The below is a sample data from dumpsys eve log. I am trying to get the fluidity metrics block with the assumption that it only contains 1m, 3m and 5m metrics. But what if in future any additional Xm is introduced, is there a generic solution for it ?

```
Fluidity:
Sample One#0
1m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
3m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
5m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
Xm: 1|2|1|0|0 total=197 dropped=4
#1
1m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
3m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
5m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
Xm: 1|2|1|0|0 total=197 dropped=4
com.sample.app1/com.android.app1.App1#0
1m: 1|2|1|0|0 total=197 dropped=4
3m: 1|2|1|0|0 total=197 dropped=4
5m: 1|2|1|0|0 total=197 dropped=4
Xm: 1|2|1|0|0 total=197 dropped=4
Xm: 1|2|1|0|0 total=197 dropped=4
com.sample.app2.identity/com.sample.App2#0
1m: 0|0|0|1|0 total=26 dropped=1
3m: 0|0|0|1|0 total=26 dropped=1
5m: 0|0|0|1|0 total=26 dropped=1
Xm: 1|2|1|0|0 total=197 dropped=4
```

The regex I created only fetch the first 3 for each activity.

```
(.*<Sample>((.*(\n|\r|\r\n)){4}))
```

This provides the match for

```
Sample Scrim#0
1m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
3m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
5m: 0|0|0|0|0 total=7 dropped=0
```

I need a generic regex that include Xm lines too in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might account for the `Xm` value using an alternation:

```
^Sample\b.*((?:\r?\n(?:\d+|X)m:.*)+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Sample\b` Match the word `Sample`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `\r?\n` Match a newline
    - `(?:\d+|X)m:.*` Match either 1+ digits or `X` and then `m:`
  - `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times to match at least 1 line
- `)` Close group 1

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2YXx8I/1)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is much helpful

Answer (score 0):

`(.*<Sample>((.*(\n|\r|\r\n)){4,}))`

Changed to quantifier to requiring 4 *or more*.

The result can be checked here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: This results in matching all the lines upto the bottom of the line. This didn't work. But thanks for your time on this